# TYPO3: Filter frontend users by usergroup in backend?

Tags: module, typo3, backend

Is there a feature or backend extension or that can filter list records? Right now, you can only check a single user record or sort by usergroup. I am looking for a module where I can choose the usergroup and get a list of all assigned users (FE users) in the backend. Or a standard feature I haven't discovered yet.

Maybe similar to filtering news articles in tt_news by category.
If it doesn't exist, I will have to code it myself.

Comment: This old extensions does the job i think. http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/group_mngr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in the List module but you can do this by setting an **action**. It can be set only by an admin but can be used by any backend user that you allow.

1. In the Extension manager check that you have **taskcenter** and **sys_action** extensions installed. Both are system extensions that come with TYPO3 by default so you don't have to download them.
2. Go to the root page (id=0) and create a new record **Action**. Set the type of the action to **SQL query** and assign a backend group of users that will be allowed to use this action.
3. Go to the **DB check** module (under Admin tools) and select **Full search** and then  **Advanced query**.
4. In the **Make query** part, set database table to **Website User** and query to **[Group] [is in list] [usergroup]**. Set other query parameters like limit of users listed and order of listing.
5. In the **Load query** part, select the action that you have created in the step 2. Click **Save**.

After backend reload, the backend users you selected in step 2 will have an action available in the top bar (see the icon next to the Clear cache icon). Upon clicking, the SQL query will be executed and the frontend users listed in the **Task center** module. If nothing shows up, make sure that you have selected **Tasks** instead of **Overview** in the **Task center**.

Comment: Thumbs up! This solution is very close, however it is not what I was wishing for. Having something like that in standard list module would be even better, cause my editors are confused when they have to use different tools for similar tasks ;). But since they can edit the user records from the action view, it is handy enough.

Comment: I am using some of these queries for quite some time now, but they are not handy at all. I appreciate your solution, but I'd be very grateful for a more practible backend filter. I will file a feature request at forge.typo3.org,

Comment: I agree with you. I rarely set this up for editors. I more likely use it for myself. Filtering in the List module would be really handy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can search for all users of a usergroup in the list module at the bottom of the page in the search box for records. I navigate to the system folder where I have my feusers I select the list module and the feuser table. Then I add the usergroup column to the view and search for a usergroup. It shows me all user assigned to this usergroup.

Comment: I already tried this, it doesn't work in any of my installations. Do I have to change something in tca or page config to achieve that?

Comment: @Mateng: My installation is broken. I can't test it but when I did on my 3 feuser it shows me all of them.

Comment: I assume that the list search field does not work with values from foreign tables. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such module yet. For a list of users, you may just click the blue info icon next to the usergroup in the list module. However there is not way to edit from there.