# Is there an extension that lists timed-out and/or hidden elements in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3

If editors frequently work with show / hide dates for pages and content elements, there is an increasing number of outdated, hidden content in the Backend.

For housekeeping, it would be nice to have an extension that lists such not-displayed content, maybe also hidden items.

Is there something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory it should be possible for admins with the "DB check -> Full search" tool. See my answer for question [typo3: what is the fast way to find which page has certain extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984288/typo3-what-is-the-fast-way-to-find-which-page-has-certain-extension/17988991)

However, I found out there is a **[bug](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/51982)** which prevents it from working as it's supposed to in TYPO3 4.5.x. I'll update this answer once the bug is fixed.

Comment: Nice, although my idea would be that editors could run it themselves

Comment: Actually, the query can be saved and used by editors. See my answer for another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666605/typo3-filter-frontend-users-by-usergroup-in-backend/9699125#9699125 I'll put it all into my answer once the bug is confirmed and resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware that there is any extension for this purpose. But you can use the list module for something similar.

Place any kind of content on your "root" page. In the list module, you now see the table "Page Content". Click on the header cell to get only "Page Content" records. In the bottom of the list module, in the search part, perform a search "4 levels down" with an empty string.

You then have all contents from the root page 4 levels down. In the field selector, select the "hidden" field. In the table, click the table head "Hide" twice to have all hidden elements on top.

Then you can bookmark this view. Not exactly what you wanted, but it gives you some kind of overview.